# Show that if $\phi \circ T$ is bounded for every $\phi\in Y^*$ then $T$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

> Show that if $T:X \to Y$ is a linear map between Banach spaces and $\phi \circ T$ is bounded for every $\phi\in Y^*$ then $T$ is bounded.

The given hint is to prove the contrapositive. 'Progress':

Suppose $T$ is unbounded. Then there exist $x_n \in X$ such that $\left\lVert x_n\right\rVert=1$ and $\left\lVert Tx_n\right\rVert \geq n$ for all $n$. For each $n$ there is a support functional $\phi_n$ at $Tx_n$: $\phi_n \in Y^*, \left\lVert \phi_n\right\rVert=1, \phi_n(Tx_n)=\left\lVert Tx_n\right\rVert$. I then applied the (contrapositive of the) Principle of Uniform Boundedness to the set of linear maps $\phi_n \circ T$ before realising that this doesn't even work because we don't know that the maps $\phi_n \circ T$ are bounded. So really I've made no progress and this is mostly to show that I've tried. Though I expect the solution will use the PUB somehow. Any small hints would be appreciated (please do not spoil the solution).

Comment: u know the maps $\phi_n\circ T$ are bounded since Hahn-Banach gives u a bounded functional $\phi_n$ and then ur condition says $\phi_n\circ T$ is bounded

Comment: I'm proving the contrapositive so I'm assuming $T$ is not bounded and trying to prove that there exists $\phi \in Y^*$ such that $\phi \circ T$ is unbounded.

Comment: yeah so u get $\phi_n\circ T$ for each bad $x_n$. These are bounded by your condition.

Comment: Ok, you can get this to work if you wish to prove it by contradiction. Assume that $T$ is unbounded but $\phi \circ T$ is bounded $\forall \phi \in Y^*$. Then $\phi_n \circ T$ is bounded but $\|(\phi_n \circ T)(x_n)\| = \|Tx_n\| \ge n$ so by PUB we get $$\|T\| = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|\phi_n\|\|T\|\ge \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|\phi_n \circ T\| = +\infty$$

Comment: I think I was being a bit silly saying that I can't progress because we don't know the $\phi_n \circ T$ are bounded - of course we can assume they are for a contradiction (otherwise we are done). Didn't quite get your proof, but does this work? We have $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left\lVert \phi_n \circ T \right\rVert = \infty$ so by PUB there is $x\in X$ such that $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |(\phi_n \circ T)(x)| = \infty$, i.e. the set $\{\phi_n (Tx)\}$ is unbounded. But $|\phi_n(Tx)| \leq \left\lVert \phi_n \right\rVert \left\lVert Tx \right\rVert=\left\lVert Tx \right\rVert$ bounded, contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Closed Graph Theorem:

Assume that $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$. For Arbitrary $\phi \in Y^*$ we have that $\phi \circ T$ is continuous so $(\phi \circ T)(x_n) \to (\phi \circ T)(x) = \phi(Tx)$. On the other hand, we have $\phi(Tx_n) \to \phi(y)$.

Uniqueness of the limit implies $\phi(Tx) = \phi(y)$ for all $\phi \in Y^*$ and hence, as the dual space is separating, $y = Tx$.
We conclude that $T$ is bounded.

Comment: We have covered the Baire Category Theorem and the Principle of Uniform Boundedness but have not yet covered the Closed Graph Theorem (though that's next). Is it possible to do this question without the CGT? It also seems strange that it was suggested to prove the contrapositive if the direct proof is so simple.

Comment: I would just add for the "hence" "as the dual space is separating".

Comment: Why must $Tx_n$ converge ?

Comment: @AlephNull If it can be solved using a direct application of PUB only, it probably wouldn't be stated that $X$ and $Y$ are both Banach spaces (this is what suggested CGT for me). For PUB it is necessary only that $X$ is Banach. I'm trying to find a counterexample now.

Comment: Yes I also found the assumption that both were Banach strange. The only results we have we which use that assumption are the Open/Inverse Mapping Theorems which seem irrelevant here. Perhaps the CGT really is the intended method. At least it admits a very easy proof as you've shown.

Comment: @AlephNull However, your proof seems to be ok if you try to prove it by contradiction, see my comment above. I guess $Y$ doesn't have to be Banach.

Answer (score 1):

Define a family of continuous linear maps $\{F_x:x\in X,\|x\|\leq 1\}$ from $Y^{*}$ to $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) by $F_x(\phi) =\phi (T(x))$. For fixed $\phi \in Y^{*}$ note that $sup \{|F_x(\phi)|:\|x\|\leq 1\}<\infty$ (by hypothesis). By Uniform Boundedness Principle we get $sup \{|F_x(\phi)|:\|x\|\leq 1, \|\phi \| \leq 1\}<\infty$. This means $T$ is bounded.